# How to prevent Zebra RFID reader going standby or in deep sleep in c#

Tags: rfid

Zebra have given SDK for connecting to RFID reader and read the tags, This i have implemented in c# and working well for somehow 10-20 minutes but after that reader stop getting reads and goes in standby mode or in deep sleep.

Tried disposing the RFID reader object and re-initiating connection if the tag wont detected in 10 seconds but it works for sometime only not for long run.

Comment: Is there anything in the log? You can also use wireshark to review the communication between your app and the reader (LLRP protocol).